# flask REST-API response problems

Tags: json, python-3.x, rest, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to send database information via REST-API and JSON, but sth have gone wrong with the response and it doesn't even appear when i test with Postman. Don't have any clue what this can be so didn't try anything. Here's the code

```
@app.route('/wells/<int:well_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_well(well_id):
    session = create_session()
    well = jsonify(session.query(Well, Well.id == well_id).first())
    session.close()
    return json.dumps(well)
```

Comment: I suggest you try returning the jsonify object as is. It is usually a good choice for returning JSON responses.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code looks valid.
In this case, add a try and except block to see if there are any exception in your codes.

```
@app.route('/wells/<int:well_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_well(well_id):
    try:
        session = create_session()
        well = jsonify(session.query(Well, Well.id == well_id).first())
    except Exception as e:
        #this will tell you if there are anything wrong
        print(e)
        #hope this help your api return something
        well = {'error':e}
    finally:
        #better to close your connection even error
        session.close()
    return json.dumps(well)
```

Also, check again on your url of postman if you type them correctly.

Comment: i tried it but it said this:
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2020 12:14:48] code 400, message Bad request version ('À\x13À')
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2020 12:14:48] " ÷  ó´t]-õ%6Û² *E{½cýÉûe9C%cì  RÈgÎ³ ±Ôe= ^´,o¸¾;1ÛÊE°`á§Ð $À/À+À0À,Ì©Ì¨À ÀÀ" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -

Comment: but i just realised this may be caused by emptyness of my database

Comment: Try add some data to your database, and of course, check your connection is valid too.

Comment: i tried to add some data through postman and it ended up with same error

Comment: I suspected if this is a encoding error? like utf-8 encoding are missing... Remember to edit your post to let more people know your current status.

Answer (score 0):

You may get it done this way

```
from flask import make_response
@app.route('/wells/<int:well_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_well(well_id):
    session = create_session()
    well = jsonify(session.query(Well, Well.id == well_id).first())
    session.close()
return make_response(well, status, headers)
```